# Transpose dynamic rows with data from MySQL in columns to PHP except headers

Tags: php, mysql

I need your help, I have this form table:

[image]

and when is submitted inserts in a MySQL DB, this table.

[image]

And i want to show that info in some table exactly like the first image like [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MetCastle/j3TW9/), I mean filled with the info from DB, but only I can get this:

[image]

I don't know how to do that, this is the code that I use, obviously don't works like I want.

```
<?php 
    $sqlStr = "SELECT prov_name, unitval, totval 
                FROM provprices where CA_id = ".$CA_id;
    $sqlStrAux = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM provprices";

$aux = Mysql_Fetch_Assoc(mysql_query($sqlStrAux));
$query = mysql_query($sqlStr);  

    if($aux['total']>0){

        echo "</br></br>";
        echo "<div class='datagrid'>";
        echo "\t<table border='1'>\n";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>
                <th>unitval</th>
                <th>totval</th>
              </tr>\n";
        echo "</thead>";      
        echo "<tbody>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
      echo "\t\t<tr>
                    <td>".htmlentities($row['unitval'])."</td>
                    <td>".$row['totval']."</td>
                </tr>\n";
    }
        echo "</tbody>";                  
        echo "\t</table>\n";
    }
        echo "</div>";
?>
```

POST Schema table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `provprices` (
  `CA_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prov_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `unitval` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `totval` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  KEY `CA_id` (`CA_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `provprices`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `provprices_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CA_id`) REFERENCES `compras_activos` (`CA_id`);
```

[image]

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: can you post the table schema please?

Comment: @JohnRuddell sure men, I edited my post. I Hope that will help you. Thanks